# Find out the total labor cost per employee per project

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm learning SQL and my code worked but I am missing some information from the original table `emp_proj` when I execute the code. The table info looks like this:

```
EMPNO | PROJNO | HOURSWORKED
------+--------+------------
1000  | 30     | 32.5
1000  | 50     | 7.5
2002  | 10     | 40
1444  | 20     | 20
1760  | 10     | 5
1760  | 20     | 10
1740  | 50     | 15
2060  | 40     | 12
```

My query:

```
select *
from emp_proj
where hoursworked in (
  select sum(hoursworked) as "Total Hours"
  from emp_proj
  group by empno
)
order by projno;
```

Output:

```
EMPNO | PROJNO | HOURSWORKED
------+--------+------------
2002  | 10     | 40
1444  | 20     | 20
2060  | 40     | 12
1740  | 50     | 15
```

I would appreciate it if someone can tell me how I can group the hours worked by every employee and project. Sorry if I'm not providing enough information.

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect. Also, please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: im expecting the same results as my output but its missing some of the employees and project numbers. for instance empno 1000 and 1760 are missing as well as projno 30

Comment: That's because they have more than one row in the table, whilst you said - with the WHERE clause - that you want hours to be equal to SUM of hours per employee, and that's true only for those who have a single row. Have a look at @shawnt00's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't guess what was the intended purpose of your `where` clause though I don't get the impression you need it anyway. (It approximates the idea of finding all employees who only worked on a single project though that still wouldn't work right.)

```
select projno, empno, sum(hoursworked)
from emp_proj
group by projno, emono
order by projno, empno;
```